# how delete from two table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day.

I have 2 table - test1 and test2.

*structure table test1:*

[image: test1]

*structure table test2:*

[image: test2]

Need use one query delete row in table *test1* where `idn='22222'` and delete all rows in table *test2* where `table2.subscription_id = table1.subscription_id`.

*Not use while or forech, only one sql query!*

*They are not foreign keys!*

Is it possible?

Comment: If they are foreign keys, then I would look at using `CASCADE DELETE`.

Comment: @bluefeet haven't foreign keys..

Comment: Maybe you should get some?

Comment: @Leo Loki - Please see if the following is of any help: <http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it is possible.

Check out the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html) for `DELETE` (they have a few passages just for multi-table deletes).

Syntax:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
FROM table_references
[WHERE where_condition]
```

In your case for example:

```
DELETE test1.*,  test2.*
FROM test1, test2
WHERE test1.subscription_id = test2.subscription_id
    AND test1.idn = '22222';
```

Other ways are possible, too.

If you'd been using foreign keys, it would be way simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Will this not work:

```
DELETE Table1, Table2
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Id = Table2.Id
WHERE Table1.Id = 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0902c/1)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
   DELETE
        test1, test2
   FROM
   test1  JOIN test2 
   WHERE
        test1.idn = 22222 AND
        test2.description_id = test1.description;
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b42a6/1)